# Trigger Onclick on Child Layered Divs with Z-index, pointer-events doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css

I want to be able to click and change the color of the background(div) with cut out by `png`.

```
<body>
  <div style="border: 1px solid red;  width: 650px; height: 500px; margin: 0px auto;  pointer-events: none; ;">
    <div class="frame" style="background-color: blue; -webkit-mask-image: url('./assets/Layer1.png'); z-index: 0"></div>
    <div class="frame" style="background-color: red; -webkit-mask-image: url('./assets/Layer2.png'); z-index: 1"></div>
    <div class="frame" style="background-color: grey; -webkit-mask-image: url('./assets/Layer3.png'); z-index: 2"></div>
    <div class="frame" style="background-color: yellow; -webkit-mask-image: url('./assets/Layer4.png'); z-index: 3"></div>
  </div>

  <style>
    .frame {
      position: absolute;
      pointer-events: auto;
      width: 640px;
      height: 490px;
      padding: 1px;
      margin: 0px auto;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style>
</body>
```

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4EGV.jpg)

Comment: any help from anyone

Comment: It's been over a year and still have no resolution to it. Please refer to image. Any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID to the parent div, and a click handler on it.

```
let parent = document.getElementById('parent')
    parent.addEventListener('click', function() {
     parent.style.backgroundColor = event.target.style.backgroundColor;
    })
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit.. but i what i wanted was to be able to click on the children divs to change the color , ie click on div1 to change the color to something or click div2 to change the color to something else....Like a ColorBook   , and i don't hava an option  to use SVG